# Apply dynamic hyperlink to the values in a dynamic dropdown in excel

Tags: google-sheets

I have two worksheets in a Google spreadsheet.

- Sheet-A: Treat this like an “order booking” page. Consists of 10 empty line items, where the user can select an item from a dynamically generated dropdown list. The values in the dynamic list come from Sheet-B’s 1st column range
- Sheet-B: Treat this like a “menu details” page. It consists of Menu item name, description, ingredients, etc

What I want to do is:

- When users try to place an order, they select a menu item from the dropdown in `Sheet A`.
- If they want to know more about an item, they should click on the hyperlink on top of the dropdown value and be navigated to the respective menu item description in `Sheet B`.

To summarize, the dynamic values coming in the dropdown list should hold a hyperlink within itself which points to where the value is coming from.

Comment: Do you have any pieces of code?

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward, use the HYPERLINK() function and either the CONCATENATE() function or use the concatenate operator "&". Here is an example from one of my projects:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://tracker.telenetwork.com/admin/reports/SCReport/report_emp.asp?emp=",$B$4,"&nt=",$A$4,"&sd=",A7,"&ed=",B7,"&dur=99999&per=15&client=",C4),"Call Recordings")
```

[image]

I built an example for another person asking a similar type question, between that example and the formula above you should be able to figure out how to implement for your specific situation. Feel free to make a copy of this sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qbLOjTdzISICTKyUp_jK6gZbQCt-OwtDYYy3HNJygeE/edit#gid=795322028

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate a bit more? I do not see how the dynamic dropdown and dynamic href working with about concatenation function